# JSON decode doesn't work cURL

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm doing a request with cURL, that sends me a response in json style.
But, i'm using the json_decode to parse the json response, and

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'example.com=');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "privatedata=teststackoverflow");
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_error($ch)) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}

echo $answer;
```

When i do $echo answer, here's the output (of curl):

```
({ "total": 1, "registro": [ { "desabilitarDataQuality": false, "solicitarAcessoPortal": false, "grauQualidade": 77, "numeroCns": "******", "nome": "**********", "nomeMae": "*******", "nomePai": "SEM INFORMAÇÃO", "sexo": "M", "dataNascimento": "*******", "paisNascimento": "*****", "municipioNascimento": "******", "emailPrincipalValidado": false, "emailAlternativoValidado": false, "nomade": false, "telefone": [], "certidao": [], "fotografia": [], "situacao": "ATIVO", "cartoesAgregados": [], "usuarioDistinto": false } ] })
```

The echo in cURL seems like json data, but when i use:

echo json_decode($answer); , there are no OUTPUT.

All data simple disappear.

Comment: Does the response include `(` and `)`? If so, that's not valid json.

Comment: You can't `echo` `json_decode()`, this function doesn't return a string

Comment: use `var_dump(json_decode($answer));` instead.

Comment: Yes, the response include ( and ). But, i'm charles web proxy debug, it shows the JSON data.

Comment: var_dump(json_decode($answer));

output = NULL

Comment: your output is definitely NOT a valid json. Post your output here https://jsonlint.com.

Comment: Write to the people who are responsible for the output from that other server, and tell them to fix their junk ;)

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at guzzle if you're doing much wit curl: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chars `(` and `)` aren't valid chars in a JSON. You can check at https://jsonlint.com/ . What you should do is to return a valid JSON.
If you aren't able to do that, you should remove this chars.

Try this code in this case:

```
$answer = curl_exec($ch);
$answer = trim($answer,'()');
$answer = json_decode($answer);
var_dump($answer);
```

Comment: I wouldn't run `substr` everytime, just in case the response comes as valid json at some point. So maybe you're looking for `trim($answer, '()')`.

Comment: Yeah, this is better.

Comment: I would not use `trim` first, but talk to `example.com=` to determine if the parens are expected behaviour.

Comment: I once had data from minfraud that came with 'quotes' around the payload. Took them 4 years to get rid of them.

Comment: array(2) { ["total"]=> int(1) ["registro"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(20) { ["desabilitarDataQuality"]=> bool(false) ["solicitarAcessoPortal"]=> bool(false) ["grauQualidade"]=> int(77) ["numeroCns"]=> string(15) "*******" ["nome"]

Still can't work with this data. Can't parse this json

Comment: This is your json. The `var_dump()` is only for you to see the data. You can erase this line. The `$answer` already has the parsed json.

Comment: I'm trying to access ["nome"] with echo $answer['nome'] but isn't working..

Comment: Try `echo $answer['registro'][0]['nome'];`

Comment: No problem. If it works for you set it as accepted answer.